# Load And Read Multiple Files In c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a program that requires that I read from multiple files and then read each line of those files.

The code I have is pretty hacked together and it seems so much so that it doesn't work.

```
void load_servers()
{
    vector<string> files;
    DIR* dir;
    dirent* pdir;

    dir = opendir("./servers");
    while (pdir = readdir(dir))
    {
        files.push_back(pdir->d_name);
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << files[i] <<endl;
    }

    ifstream f;

    for (int i = 2; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        f.open(files[i].c_str());
        string str;
        vector<string> svr;
        while (getline(f, str))
        {
            svr.push_back(str);
        }
        cout << svr[0] << endl;
//        servers.push_back(SERVER(svr[0], sve[1], svr[2]));
    }
}
```

It instantly crashes when it hits `cout << svr[0] << endl;`

Running windows 8.1 and MinGW 4.9

Comment: The file is not empty no? Please add a `f.close();` to the end of the loop and try.

Comment: Added `f.close();` Still crashes without any error.

Comment: The crash error? And the file in what fail has content?

Comment: The file has 3 lines. the only crash error I get is `<exe name> has stopped working`

Comment: Сheck whether the file is opened successfully. Like `f.good()` for example before call `getline`

Comment: Gah, I'm dumb. This is why I shouldn't stay up all night. changed the f.open call to `f.open("./servers/"+files[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

If `std::getline()` fails there will be nothing in `svr` and `svr[0]` will be accessing unallocated memory.

I recommend you to put some error checking in your program because it is overly optimistic to expect everything to always work out.

For example:

```
for (int i = 2; i < files.size(); i++)
{
    // declaring the ifstream inside the loop should
    // ensure its resources get cleaned up each iteration
    ifstream f(files[i].c_str());

    if(!f.is_open()) // check the open actually worked
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: opening file: " << files[i] << '\n';
        continue; // skip rest of loop
    }

    string str;
    vector<string> svr;
    while (getline(f, str))
    {
        svr.push_back(str);
    }

    if(svr.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "File empty: " << files[i] << '\n';
        continue;
    }

    // process vector here

    cout << svr[0] << endl;
}
```